# Simple jQuery Price Updating problems dropdown vs radio button

Tags: jquery

So I figured out how to update price via jQuery, with radio buttons:

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/pcvr7h2b/5/

Now the problem I am having is applying the exact same function to the dropdowns, so the "option" values. I want the price to change when a dimension is selected in the dropdown.

I added in the code here:

```
$("option:selected").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("value");
  total += parseInt(value);
});
```

Trying to get this to work, but was having no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a look at your code, the style is not so good, if I need to give you a solution, I need to rewrite everything. Hence, I only offer some suggestions. 1. calcTotal() function can calculate the total amount of everything, then has a return value. 2. your options do not have a value which corresponding to the cost. 3. it is better to have an id for the cost value, then just use the id to update the value of cost every time when the event is fired. 4 it should be better if you use div or other html tag to arrange your html layout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But yeah there is not point in styling something until it is fully functional. The output just needs to be a temporary output. Because everything else as far as the actual price is calculated in the back end of ultracart. But yeah the options don't have values in the example you see because the jquery for the options isn't working. Ultracart uses tables for the base HTML, but yeah divisions would be added in later for styling when things get fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ultracart is. 
Regardless of ultracart, here is how I will implement for your purpose. 
http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/01ekur6u/

```
function total(){
     var total = 0;
     var opt3 = parseInt($("select[name='OptionValue3'] option:selected").val());
     var opt4 = parseInt($("select[name='OptionValue4'] option:selected").val());
     total = opt3 + opt4;
     return total;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     var num = total();
     $("#total").append(num);

     $("select").on('change', function(){
          num=total();
          $("#total").html(num);
     });

});
```

See if you can merge this to your main code, and hope it works for your purpose.

Comment: By the way, it is the best to present your code in a nice style, because they are easy to read, and people may feel easier to help you out.

Comment: If you are looking for a much simpler example of what you posted you can find that here: http://jsfiddle.net/gjbKY/10/ I can look at that code all day but for some reason I can't figure out how to add the change function on the option:selected. It works alone, but it doesn't function when I add in the input:checked

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jnhxdztr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".add").each(function() {
        $(this).bind("click keyup", function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("input.add:checked, select .add:selected, input.add:not(:radio)").each(function() {
        console.log(this);
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```